# Titanium x-platform app progress bar not showing on android

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm currently working on an app that is using a tableview. Each row displays certain information and some rows should have a progress bar showing the user how far the event is according to the schedule.

On iOS the following code snippet will get me the progress bar (with demo value in the snippet) I want, but on Android I wont get anything. It makes sense to me that Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN won't work for Android but I am unable to find how to apply the correct style for android. even if I leave it out I don't even get a bar on android like I do on iOS.

```
var myProgress = Ti.UI.createProgressBar({
top:50,
width: '100%',
height:4,
min:0,
max:10,
value: 5,
style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN
})


self.add(myProgress);
myProgress.show();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Example on how it is displayed in iOS :

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/2e5nxts.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

This works well by my on Android. As you are displaying them on rows, I would say that your property with "top" make them be too low. Try to comment that line to see if it shows.

I had a similar issue where I could not see the bar but it was indeed there (only the value was zero...).

Florence.